# Надо ли тут перед математическим выражением двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

Агент управления производством  сравнивал себестоимость E с рыночной стоимостью продукта Р и сокращал (или останавливал) выпуск продукции, когда нарушалось условие рентабельности производства EF: себестоимость производства становилась выше стоимости: E>P.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо двоеточия лучше использовать **скобки**, так как в предложении уже есть двоеточие. Кроме того, это **дополнительная информация** (математическая запись уже сказанного). Можно также использовать **пояснительный союз** А ИМЕННО.

Агент управления производством сравнивал себестоимость E с рыночной стоимостью продукта Р и сокращал (или останавливал) выпуск продукции, когда нарушалось условие рентабельности производства EF, **а именно**: себестоимость производства становилась выше стоимости **(E>P).**

М

Answer (score 0):

Вместо "сравнивал себестоимость E с рыночной стоимостью продукта Р" лучше сказать ""сравнивал себестоимость **продукта** E с его рыночной стоимостью Р". Термин "себестоимость производства" весьма сомнительного происхождения. Себестоимость  -  характеристика продукта, а не производства. Если при расчете себестоимости учитываются только затраты на производство, употребляют термин "производственная себестоимость".